# Syntax Error while accessing a field in a record

Tags: erlang, record

I'm having a problem that should be stupidly easy to fix. Following [this](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/records.html#id76826), I'm trying to access a field in a record. Here's a simplified example that exhibits my problem:

```
-module(test).
-export([test/0]).

-record(rec, {f1=[], f2=[], f3=[]}).

test() ->
    Rec = #rec{f1=[1,2,3], f3=[4,5,6]},
    Fields = record_info(fields, rec),
    loop(Fields, Rec).

loop([Field|Fields], Rec) ->
    [Rec#rec.Field|loop(Fields, Rec)]; %% <-- This is line 12.
loop([], _Rec) ->
    [].
```

When I try to compile test, I get a syntax error:

```
./test.erl:12: syntax error before: Field
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to pack a run-time concern into compile-time. That means that you are trying to evaluate and replace Field by its real value [which is available during program execution] during program compilation. Generally the problem is solved by preprocessing or metaprogramming. Unfortunately I do not know what's the best approach for Erlang.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to enumerate record values you can use [element/2](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#element-2) and enumerate elements from 2 ([the first element is a record name](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/records.html#id76991)) to [tuple_size](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#tuple_size-1)(Record).

If you want to access record fields by name at run time you can create auxiliary proplist at compile time like this:

```
Fields = lists:zip(record_info(fields, rec),
                   lists:seq(2, record_info(size, rec)))
```

**Note that record_info() always evaluated at compile time.**

And then query field value with function similar to this:

```
get_record_value(Name, Record, Fields) ->
    case proplists:get_value(Name, Fields) of
        undefined ->
            undefined;
        N when is_integer(N) ->
            element(N, Record)
    end.
```

Comment: I'm accepting this one, since it solves the problem stated in the question, but it turned out that my code could be restructured to not need to do this at all (I ended up cutting out about half my code). Hooray!

Answer (score 1):

Records are converted into arrays in compile-time, meaning that all field accesses are converted to erlang:element calls as well. Thus variables cannot be used as field names must be known at compile-time - as Damg already answered.

The "workarounds" I am aware of are either using proplists, dicts, etc. instead of records, or use Ulf Wiger's [exprecs](http://github.com/esl/parse_trans) to generate record access functions.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is converting the record into a proplist and using the `proplists` library module to iterate or access specific fields. This example:

```
-module(test).
-export([start/0]).
-record(test, {value1, value2, value3}).

start() ->
    R = #test{value1=1, value2=2, value3=3},
    Fields = record_info(fields, test),
    Values = tl(tuple_to_list(R)),
    lists:zip(Fields, Values).
```

Will produce the following proplist:

```
> c("test").
> Proplist = test:start().
[{value1,1},{value2,2},{value3,3}]
```

Then for example to get value of field `value2`:

```
> proplists:get_value(value2, Proplist).
2
```