# do record_info and tuple_to_list return the same key order in Erlang?

Tags: erlang, record, tuples

I.e, if I have a record

```
-record(one, {frag, left}).
```

- Is `record_info(fields, one)` going to *always* return `[frag,
  left]`?
- Is `tl(tuple_to_list(#one{frag = "Frag", left = "Left"}))`
  *always* gonna be `["Frag", "Left"]`?

Is this an implementation detail?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is: yes, as of this writing it will work. The better answer is: it may not work that way in the future, and the nature of the question concerns me.

It's safe to use `record_info/2`, although relying on the order may be risky and frankly I can't think of a situation where doing so makes sense which implies that you are solving a problem the wrong way. Can you share more details about what exactly you are trying to accomplish so we can help you choose a better method? It could be that simple pattern matching is all you need.

As for the example with `tuple_to_list/1`, I'll quote from "Erlang Programming" by Cesarini and Thompson:

> "... whatever you do, never, ever use the tuple representations of records in your programs. If you do, the authors of this book will disown you and deny any involvement in helping you learn Erlang."

There are several good reasons why, including:

1. Your code will become brittle - if you later change the number of fields or their order, your code will break.
2. There is no guarantee that the internal representation of records will continue to work this way in future versions of erlang.

Comment: Well, I'm writing a REST service and I need to be able to convert between proplists and records - in that case, I would use `record_info/2` and `tuple_to_list/` together *only* - so changing the order or adding and removing fields wouldn't break the code, provided that the field order is retained between those two functions. That said, is there a better way to accomplish that?

Comment: You should take a look at Ulf Wiger's [exprecs](https://github.com/esl/parse_trans/blob/master/src/exprecs.erl) to dynamically create records without relying on the internal tuple structure.

Comment: I read somewhere that this is gonna short-circuit the compiler's ability to optimize record access, but I guess it doesn't matter.

Comment: Piqi (protobuffs) parses binaries into predefined record. I had a situation where I needed to convert something from a protobuff format into a standardized internal format. The way I went about this was to do exactly as described in the question with a fold (actually a "zip_fold" function I wrote), same concept; e.g., `lists:foldl(fun my_parser, #my_record{}, lists:zip(record_info(fields, piqi_record), tl(tuple_to_list(PiqiTuple))))`. The code breaks if modules or mnesia tabs are not updated (transform_table), but this is easily handled with smart relups. exprecs is probably a better solution.

Comment: I should add that the code only breaks if you make a change to the record definition, but I ran out of characters. It's really not that much of a hassle in my estimation. The real challenge will be if Erlang changes the internal representation of records.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in both cases Erlang will retain the 'original' order. And yes it's implementation as it's not specifically addressed in the function spec or documentation, though it's a pretty safe bet it will stay like that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, order is always the same because records represented by tuples for which order is an essential property. Look also on my other answer about records with examples: [Syntax Error while accessing a field in a record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001477/syntax-error-while-accessing-a-field-in-a-record/4004850#4004850)